# How to pass the formatted text of textarea to other php page?

Tags: php, textarea

I just want to get the value as I have formatted on the page before on textarea as it is using this code. Also pre tag didn't work for me. Anybody any idea?

```
<?php
  $val=$_GET['valuefromtextarea'];
  echo $val;
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `GET` request to pass data from `textarea`. Use `POST`. And check `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you're asking.  A `textarea` value posts just like any other `form` element value.  In what way is this not working?  Can you show a more complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: When you say formatted what you mean? is it containing html code?
If so i recommend you to use a javascript function to encode the text in the textbox and the php receiving the variable do an urldecode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is core/standard PHP:

```
<form method="GET">
    <textarea name="myfield">foo bar baz</textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php     
    $text = $_GET['myfield'];
    echo "You entered: $text<br />"; // outputs "foo bar baz"
```

Comment: if the content is large say paragraph. While simply using the code above and echoing the content. everthing seems to be concatenated.

Comment: of course it is. you're outputting text in an html context, so html rendering rules apply. If you want to maintain the formatting, then use a `<pre>...</pre>` block, or change the server's output to text/plain

Comment: and that's where my problem is!!! the <pre>..</pre> blocks are not working for me. Probably the format is not maintained while passing the value this way. Any idea?

Comment: can't help you without knowing what kind of formatting/text you've got in your text area. if it's html code, then remember that even with `<pre>` tags, the html tags in your inseerted text are still going to be rendered.

Comment: what if I have to copy the exact contents to a file?

Comment: you've got a display problem. what comes out of $_GET/$_POST is exactly what got submitted from the form. as long as you don't manipulate that data, it'll go into your file exactly as it came from the browser.

Comment: You didn't get my question. What if want to write the exact content of textarea to a other file say 'test.txt' without the format being changed?

Comment: I did get your question. `file_put_contents('test.txt', $_GET['yourfield'])` will dump into the file EXACTLY what was received from the client. If you get different formatting, then something is mangling the text before it reaches the server.

Comment: I know that's what I have been trying to do but just not getting idea what's messing around over here. Anyway Thank-you. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get the information and dump it into a database you will not be able to get it formatted. if you want to output the information somewhere else you may wanna try prittify:

https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Not the one I was looking for but thanks prettify seems to be quite useful